# NextJs "Warning: Text content did not match. Server" when setting <style> tag?

Tags: next.js

In my NextJS app Im applying CSS in a `<style>` tag based on values from state. I dont mind if this component is client only.

Im getting a strange behaviour. If I return a div it works as expected. If I return a `<style>` tag it works but I get an error:

> Warning: Text content did not match. Server:

```
// In src/app/page.tsx
"use client";
export default function Home(){
  return <Child />
}

// In child:
"use client";
export default function Child(){
  const snap = useSnapshot(state);
  if(!snap.styles) return null;
  const styles = snap.styles.map(style => `.{style.class} { ${style.rule} }`)
  return(
    <>
      <div>{styles}</div>
      <style>{styles}</style>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: If you add `<style jsx>` instead, does it solve your issue? Otherwise you could always import this component using `dynamic` NextJs import, and disable the SSR there to avoid this issue.